# Smtp server not returning error

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, openssl

I have problem with checking existing of gmail account. For connecting to smtp server i use openssl for Windows. After run i writing next line to connect to server:

```
s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587
```

After connect, i login on server using auth login.
After this i starting to create new mail:

```
C:mail from:<somegmail@gmail.com>
S:250 2.1.0 OK w7sm27345781wiz.0
C:rcpt to:<incorrectEmail@asas.com>  //input incorrect email
S:250 2.1.0 OK w7sm27345781wiz.0
```

But after input incorrect email server must return error:

```
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist...
```

Why server not return error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sending server accepts your message, for sending, but does not check if the destination is actually valid at this time. That is why you have a success message.

The server is basically telling you: "Ok I have your message and will try to deliver it"

It will be later, when the gmail.com server talks with the asas.com server, that the asas.com server will give an error, at which time you will receive a bounce email from Gmail